# Add Selectable Class on table cell selection

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectable

I have one html table.

```
<table id="tbl_1">
    <tr>
        <td>ABCD</td>
        <td>ABCD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ABCD</td>
        <td>ABCD</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I can add `selectable` class like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     jQuery('#tbl_1').selectable({
         filter: "td"
     });
});
```

I want to add `selectable` class to that table when i select more than one cell of table. I don't know on which event i can do this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You mean how we select with `ctrl+click` or `shift+click`

Comment: @GuruprasadRao select table cell just like how we select any text using mouse.

Answer (score 0):

You can add seletable class to the table by using below code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {      
     jQuery('#tbl_1').addClass('selectable');        
});
//it add class when page load
```

Comment: I know that but i want to add class on table cell selection.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#tbl_1").selectable({
    filter: "td",
    selecting: function (event, ui) {
        $(ui.selecting).addClass('classA');
    },
    unselecting: function (event, ui) {
        $(ui.unselecting).removeClass('classA');
    },
    selected: function (event, ui) {
        $(ui.selected).addClass('classB');
    },
    unselected: function (event, ui) {
        $(ui.unselected).removeClass('classB');
    }
});
```

Following are the function you can use whichever suits your combination

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/CjT3r/8/)